# Get unit price and expiration date of a trial license for a 365 tenant

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to fetch the details of a tenants licenses,
Specifically trying to check whether they are trials and if so, when they are expiring.
Is it possible to get that information using the Microsoft Graph API?
If not, which way do you recommend?
I prefer not using MSOL since it's deprecated.

[image]

I've tried using Microsoft Graph, get-MgSubscribedSku and Get-MgSubscription -SubscriptionId
Both didn't give me the information.